# How do I detect 64-bit Java from the command line?

Tags: java, windows

Is there any way to get at Java internal properties, such as *sun.arch.data.model* , from a command line on windows?   I need a command to put in a batch script that will detect the java architecture type: 32-bit or 64-bit .

Comment: Could you write a small java app to do that and call it from your batch script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Sun's VM (and I would suppose other VMs have similar details in their version information), you can check for the string "64-Bit" in the output of "java -version":

```
java -version 2>&1 | find "64-Bit" >nul:

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo 32-Bit 
) else (
    echo 64-Bit
)
```

Answer (score 2):

jarnbjo's script is for Windows. In Unix shell, you can use the following script.

```
  #!/bin/sh

  BIT=`java -version 2>&1`

  case "$BIT" in
    *64-Bit*)
    echo "64-Bit"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "32-Bit"
    ;;
  esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a prewritten property dump program for you: [linky](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/DumpProps.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you install [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) you can use

```
groovy -e "System.properties.each{println it}"
```

for all properties, and

```
groovy -e "println System.properties['sun.arch.data.model']"
```

for specific properties.

Installing Groovy is as easy as extracting a zip and add to path.